# Parent Query Listing in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

wanted to list  Parent and Child
data from single code  column in table
which contain Parent and  Child
in Same column one below the other

| Code | Description |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4000 | Agriculture | Parent |
| 4010 | Crops Production | Child |
| 4011 | Fishery | Child |
| 4100 | Mining and Quarying | Perents |
| 4110 | Non Metal Quarying | Child |
| 4111 | Others | Child |

Result should be as below:

| Code | Description | Result Column1 | Result Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4000 | Agriculture | Agriculture |  |
| 4010 | Crops Production |  | Crops Production |
| 4011 | Fishery |  | Fishery |
| 4100 | Mining and Quarying | Mining and Quarying |  |
| 4110 | Non Metal Quarying |  | Non Metal Quarying |
| 4111 | Others |  | Others |

Need oracle SQL statement to list only parents in one column and respective Child in other column.

Comment: Thank you for the support I am  able to List the Parent and child

I am  looking for the  accumulation of total of Child  in to parent  
 Although I am able to get the Child total  
Can any one Assist for the same below is the Required Output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your parents have a `code` that ends in `00` and children have a code that does not end in `00` with the same leading digits as the parent then you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT code,
       description,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 1 THEN description END AS result_column1,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN description END AS result_column2
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL <= 2
START WITH MOD(code, 100) = 0
CONNECT BY TRUNC(PRIOR code / 100) = TRUNC(code / 100)
AND        PRIOR code < code
ORDER SIBLINGS BY code
```

But you can probably simplify it to just:

```sql
SELECT code,
       description,
       CASE WHEN code LIKE '%00' THEN description END AS result_column1,
       CASE WHEN code NOT LIKE '%00' THEN description END AS result_column2
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY code;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Code, Description) AS
SELECT 4000, 'Agriculture'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4010, 'Crops Production'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4011, 'Fishery'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4100, 'Mining and Quarying' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4110, 'Non Metal Quarying'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4111, 'Others'              FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| CODE | DESCRIPTION | RESULT_COLUMN1 | RESULT_COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4000 | Agriculture | Agriculture | *null* |
| 4010 | Crops Production | *null* | Crops Production |
| 4011 | Fishery | *null* | Fishery |
| 4100 | Mining and Quarying | Mining and Quarying | *null* |
| 4110 | Non Metal Quarying | *null* | Non Metal Quarying |
| 4111 | Others | *null* | Others |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XD0XC_-Y)